# Can I create a custom class that can be initialized with curly bracers?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to build my own class in C# that is initialized by multiple parameters with curly bracers, like `string[]`

```
string[] x = new string[] {
"string1",
"string2",
"string3"
}
```

Is it possible?

**Edit** I am sorry for not making myself clear. I wanted a class that can be initialized in an elegant way, with variable amount of parameters.

Comment: I wonder if taking an IEnumerable as a constructor argument would be enough...

Comment: Is the key feature the use of curly braces, the open-ended parameter list, or something else?

Comment: What are you expecting your syntax to look like? What result? What is the shape of a single element of the list you are desiring to initialize with?

Comment: @CodeGnome - I've updated my question. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To support [collection initializer syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx), your class needs to implement [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) and have a public **Add** method.

*Example:*

```
class MyClass : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public void Add(int value) { ... }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator() { ... }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { ... }
}
```

*Usage:*

```
var myClass = new MyClass { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

---

Alternatively, you can define a constructor that takes a variable number of arguments. You can do this using the [**params** keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx).

*Example:*

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(params int[] args) { ... }
}
```

*Usage:*

```
var myClass = new MyClass(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax above is for initializing an array, not a class.  You can, however, initialize properties in the class through a constructor such as:

```
MyClass foo = new MyClass()
   {
     X = 1,
     Y = 2
   };
```

This is the same as doing:

```
MyClass foo = new MyClass();
foo.X = 1;
foo.Y = 2;
```

Comment: Oh, definitely look at dtb's answer about "Collection Initializers" as well - I had forgotten about that :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is! Sine C# 3.0 (i think) any instance can be initialized using list initializers!

Example:

```
class Foo
{
   public int X { get; set; }
   public int Y { get; set; }

}

Foo f = new Foo() { X = 10, Y = 20 };
```

Comment: 2 props with the same name not gonna happen.

Answer (score 1):

See it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx

```
List<StudentName> students = new List<StudentName>()
{
  new StudentName {FirstName="Craig", LastName="Playstead", ID=116},
  new StudentName {FirstName="Shu", LastName="Ito", ID=112},
  new StudentName {FirstName="Gretchen", LastName="Rivas", ID=113},
  new StudentName {FirstName="Rajesh", LastName="Rotti", ID=114}
};
```